# Inter frames communication

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Use case is, two frames loaded by two different projects.
e.g.

farme 1 is loaded by **test.dev.com**
frame 2 is loaded by **load.dev.com**

and this page resides in **test.dev.com**.  Frame 2 has a save button.  Frame 1 should know when close button was clicked. Or can Frame 2 provide a call back function to frame 1.

Comment: So, what do you want help with exactly?  I hope you don't expect someone to write the code for you.

Comment: certainly not. checking, if this could be really possible, is there a way two frames could be aware of, what's happening on the other frame

Answer (score 0):

Frames are separate DOM's and can not interract, technically, with other frames.
The only way to make it appear that they are is using some kind of ajax or "frame manager" loaded at the top level that all frames have access to, and pass the HTML elements that are needed back and forth.  Better to let frames be standalone and not dependent on each other.